# cheat engine debug breakpoint on IDA function addresses

Tags: lua, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida, cheat-engine

I have this function (4F314A) on IDA that I like to understand when / if will call:

[image]

I like to add a breakpoint to cheat engine and I have used this code:

```
debugProcess()  -- Attach Debugger to the process.
function debugger_onBreakpoint()

   print("hello hacking")


    return 0 --Break

end

myaddress=getAddress("battlezone2.exe")+0x4F314A
debug_setBreakpoint(myaddress); -- Address where to set breakpoint
```

but don't do nothing and I don't sure if is correct.

Is this the right way to add a breakpoint to cheat engine to see if a assembly function will call ?

Thanks !

Comment: Thank you, there is a way with cheat engine or other to print a message or break the game when the function 4F314A will call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can only see if the function will call via a debugger and a breakpoint right before an instruction you know will execute

Try setting a breakpoint at the first/second instruction

Also, I believe you meant this:

```lua
openProcess("battlezone2.exe") -- If you dont have it attached yet, this will do it
debugProcess()  -- Attach Debugger to the process.
function debugger_onBreakpoint()
    print("hello hacking")
    return 0 -- Returns 0 to Cheat engine

end

myaddress = getAddress("0x4F314A")
debug_setBreakpoint(myaddress); -- Address where to set breakpoint
```

[getAddress](https://wiki.cheatengine.org/index.php?title=Lua:getAddress) takes a [CEAddressString](https://wiki.cheatengine.org/index.php?title=CEAddressString) as first parameter, not the process name.